# Converting CDT timestamp into UTC format in spark scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My Dataframe, myDF is like bellow -

```
DATE_TIME
Wed Sep  6 15:24:27 CDT 2017
Wed Sep  6 15:30:05 CDT 2017
```

Expected output in format :

```
2017-09-06 15:24:27
2017-09-06 15:30:05
```

Need to convert DATE_TIME timestamp to UTC.

Tried the below code in databricks notebook but it's not working.

```
%scala

val df = Seq(("Wed Sep  6 15:24:27 CDT 2017")).toDF("times")
df.withColumn("times2",date_format(to_timestamp('times,"ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss CDT yyyy"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).show(false)

times                        | times2    
Wed Sep  6 15:24:27 CDT 2017 | null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we need to remove **`wed`** from your string then use **`to_timestamp()`** function.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show(false)
/*
+---------------------------+
|times                      |
+---------------------------+
|Wed Sep 6 15:24:27 CDT 2017|
+---------------------------+
*/

df.withColumn("times2",expr("""to_timestamp(substring(times,5,length(times)),"MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy")""")).
show(false)
/*
+---------------------------+-------------------+
|times                      |times2             |
+---------------------------+-------------------+
|Wed Sep 6 15:24:27 CDT 2017|2017-09-06 15:24:27|
+---------------------------+-------------------+
*/
```

Comment: Thank you so much .Its working fine now .Great brother .